# Compare old and updated fields in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to compare old and updated field in model. I have did this issue for one field but i want do this for all fields:

```
class MyUser(User)
    def save(self, **kwargs):
       if self.pk is not None:
         orig = MyUser.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
         orig_field_names = orig._meta.get_all_field_names()
         field_names = self._meta.get_all_field_names()
         # I want do this in loop 
         if orig.first_name != self.first_name:
           print 'first_name changed'
           UpdateLog.objects.create(
                user = orig,
                filed_name = self.first_name,
                update_time = datetime.now()
             )
         super(MyUser, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my go-to function for comparing fields. Gets a little hairy when dealing with foreign keys, but it's not too bad overall:

```
def get_changes_between_objects(object1, object2, excludes=[]):
    """
    Finds the changes between the common fields on two objects

    :param object1: The first object
    :param object2: The second object
    :param excludes: A list of field names to exclude
    """
    changes = {}

    # For every field in the model
    for field in object1._meta.fields:
        # Don't process excluded fields or automatically updating fields
        if not field.name in excludes and not isinstance(field, fields.AutoField):
            # If the field isn't a related field (i.e. a foreign key)..
            if not isinstance(field, fields.related.RelatedField):
                old_val = field.value_from_object(object1)
                new_val = field.value_from_object(object2)
                # If the old value doesn't equal the new value, and they're
                # not both equivalent to null (i.e. None and "")
                if old_val != new_val and not(not old_val and not new_val):
                    changes[field.verbose_name] = (old_val, new_val)

            # If the field is a related field..
            elif isinstance(field, fields.related.RelatedField):
                if field.value_from_object(object1) != field.value_from_object(object2):
                    old_pk = field.value_from_object(object1)
                    try:
                        old_val = field.related.parent_model.objects.get(pk=old_pk)
                    except field.related.parent_model.DoesNotExist:
                        old_val = None

                    new_pk = field.value_from_object(object2)
                    try:
                        new_val = field.related.parent_model.objects.get(pk=new_pk)
                    except field.related.parent_model.DoesNotExist:
                        new_val = None

                    changes[field.verbose_name] = (old_val, new_val)

    return changes
```

Usage:

```
>>> item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> item_old = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> print item.my_attribute
'foo'
>>> item.my_attribute = 'bar'
>>> get_changes_between_objects(item, item_old)
{'My Attribute': ('bar', 'foo')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).  For quick reference, here's the introductory paragraph or so from that link:

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps decoupled
> applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the
> framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a
> set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially
> useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.
>
> Django provides a set of built-in signals that let user code get
> notified by Django itself of certain actions.

Comment: why -1? Could you please write any comment or suggestion?

Comment: Because signals can't help to compare objects in any way.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: By themselves, no signals don't do anything special to compare old and new values, but a signal is still the correct approach: particularly `pre_save`. You query the existing object in the DB and compare it against the passed-in instance. Especially for something like creating a log, the code should be in a signal receiver, not the model.

Comment: @DrTyrsa before voting (two times) negative ... you must be sure. Thanks Chris Pratt

Comment: @Chris Pratt I totally agree, signals are correct here, it can be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: Comments are very limiting. There's no problem in answering a question with a different approach entirely instead of using the OP's current methodology. The OP can choose to not accept that one, but it benefits other who may have the same question. Granted, Goin's answer doesn't really provide an alternative approach so much, but you should then down-vote because the answer is not comprehensive, not because it suggests doing it in a different way.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Doing what? That was the question and no answer provided. Though I don't want to step into long discussion. May be you are right, but I believe good question will recieve more upvotes than downvotes, so my -1 won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs before vote -1. Catch the signal is the better way to do this thing

Comment: Very,very helpful answer. OP doesn't ask about the way to do this thing, he (or she) asks about the thing itself. It's also better not to call `get_all_field_names` twice (the result is same), to use logging better than `print` and to fix a typo in `filed_name`. But all these aren't answers to OP's question. And that's why '-1'.